# hovering effect jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following unordered list I want to hide when not hovered over and show when hovered over.

```
<ul class="viewer">
<li><a href=".html">Menu</a></li>
<div>
<ul>
<li><a href=".html">1</a></li>
<li><a href=".html">2</a></li>
<li><a href=".html">3</a></li>
<li><a href=".html">4</a></li>
<li><a href=".html">5</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The css is the following

```
div ul li {visibility: hidden;}
```

As you can see I have wrapped the list items in a div and set the visibility to hidden.

Now according to the hover method in jQuery, you should be able to on a very simple basis set the visibility of the list items to visible simply by

```
$('ul li')

.hover

(function()
{
.css("visibility","visible");
}

),

(function()
{
.css("visibility","hidden");

});
```

What makes me a little unsure is the $('ul li'). And also, is it ok to add a css feature inside of a hovering effect as i have done? I wasnt sure if I should add the css to a function as i have done.
All tips are appreciated.

Comment: Your code is full of syntax errors. jQuery is javascript, not some pseudo css language.

Comment: your mark up has an error too. the first ul is not closed

Comment: @Esailija please keep calm. Not everyone thinks of programming like some sort of lifestyle. I am trying to create some features for my site. So keep your thoughts to yourself and just answer my Q

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery or even JavaScript for that, just use the CSS pseudo-class `:hover`. Imagine a user that doesn't enable JavaScript...

```
ul li{
  // style of your list
  visibility: hidden;
}

ul li:hover{
  // style of your list when hovered
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Also, you don't need to wrap your list into a `div` here, don't wrap element unless you have a good reason to do so. It slows down the rendering of your site in the browser.

Comment: if you set the ul to hidden. it wont show the Menu. in other words you need a div

Answer (score 0):

you could also try to use the hide() command.

```
this.hide();
```

or

```
this.show();
```

that should work ^^

to get your own script working, you should change this:

```
.css("visibility","visible");
```

into this:

```
this.css("visibility","visible");
```